# Does Google Apps for Education include a centralized timetable management system?

Tags: google-workspace

Does Google Apps for Education offer a centralized timetable management system?

My department has many classrooms and labs within its control and the timetable making process gets difficult on MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

You could use resource calendars o regular calendars from Google Calendar as classroom calendars.

## Explanation

From [1]

> Google Calendar makes it easy to manage resources such as conference
> rooms, basketball courts, or classrooms. Simply create a new calendar
> for your resource, select the appropriate acceptance level for
> automatically adding events to the calendar, and then share your
> calendar with the people who will be reserving the resource. When this
> calendar is added to an event's guest list, it will accept the
> invitation (depending on the selected acceptance level) and the
> resource will be reserved.

From [2]

> A calendar resource is anything you schedule that isn't an event. The
> most common example is a meeting room. Other examples might include
> projectors, company fleet cars, guest offices, recreation equipment,
> or any other resource that the people in your organization might
> schedule a time to use.
>
> To create and manage resources:
>
> 1. Create resources
> 2. Manage calendar resources
> 3. Share calendar resources
> 4. Add resources to an event
> 5. Get resource notifications

## References

- [1] [Create a calendar for shared resources (conference rooms, sports fields, etc.) - Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/34584?hl=en)
- [2] [About calendar resources (rooms, etc) - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1686462?hl=en)

Comment: thanku, but how about a way which maintains a database?

Comment: @user119070 What do you mean by `maintains a database`?